# PDFLATEX : Cover Page Image with No Margin

Tags: graphics, pdftex, minipage, tikz-styles, exam

I'm creating exam paper using exam class as mentioned below:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,addpoints,answers,10pt]{exam}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\TileWallPaper{\paperwidth}{1\paperheight}{QPborder}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=1.25\linewidth, height=1.15\textheight, keepaspectratio=true]{Std3Qpcover}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Before Starting questions, I want to add image on the first page occupying full size of A4 page (without margin & wallpaper background). 
I tried many options already mentioned on the forum, but somehow nothing is working. Can you please suggest, how can I add full page Image without margin & border & background image?

Comment: Have you tried moving `\TileWallPaper{\paperwidth}{1\paperheight}{QPborder}` in the document and outside of the preamble?

Comment: Yes, I tried even completely removing it from the document to check if image "Std3Qpcover" comes with full page, but no luck till now

Comment: See related question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14696/full-page-image-as-title-page?rq=1

Comment: Do files QPborder and Std3Qpcover have extensions?  If so, you need to use them.

Comment: Thanks a LOT John. Using suggested question mentioned above, I'm resolve this problem. Thanks again.