# How can I include a title image at the lower part of the title page?

Tags: titles

I currently have the following page as a title page:

[image]

The left title pages is with `\vspace{10cm}` / `\vspace{5cm}`, the right one without. The upper ones are in A4 page format (for students to print), the lower ones are in A5 format (for professional printing).

I think the ones on the left look much better. But I would like to have the space inserted "dynamically" (so that I don't have to change this every time I change the format). How can I do this?

This is the source ([sources with image](https://github.com/MartinThoma/LaTeX-examples/tree/master/documents/GeoTopo-titlepage)):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,DIV15,BCOR12mm]{scrbook}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}% math symbols / fonts
\usepackage{mathtools}      % \xRightarrow
\usepackage{nicefrac}       % \nicefrac
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % this is needed for umlauts
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % this is needed for umlauts
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % this is needed for correct output of umlauts in pdf
\usepackage[framed,amsmath,thmmarks,hyperref]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{makeidx} % for automatically generation of an index
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[bookmarks,bookmarksnumbered,hypertexnames=false,pdfpagelayout=OneColumn,colorlinks,hyperindex=false]{hyperref} % has to be after makeidx
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tabto}
\usepackage{braket}         % needed for \Set
\usepackage{csquotes}       % \enquote{}
\usepackage{subfig}         % multiple figures in one
\usepackage{parskip}        % nicer paragraphs
\usepackage{xifthen}        % \isempty
\usepackage{changepage}     % for the adjustwidth environment
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}
\usepackage[arrow, matrix, curve]{xy}
\usepackage{caption}        % get newlines within captions
\usepackage{tikz}           % draw
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}    % draw
\usepackage{tkz-fct}        % draw
\usetikzlibrary{3d,calc,intersections,er,arrows,positioning,shapes.misc,patterns,fadings,decorations.pathreplacing}
\usepackage{tqft}
\usepackage{cleveref} % has to be after hyperref, ntheorem, amsthm
\usepackage{xspace}   % for new commands; decides weather I want to insert a space after the command

\author{Siehe \href{http://tinyurl.com/GeoTopo}{tinyurl.com/GeoTopo}}
\title{Geometrie und Topologie\\
        \vspace{10cm}
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{figures/Torus.pdf}}
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

I thought I could make a [full page as title page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14696/5645). But this might cause problems with font size.

Comment: What exactly do you want? Did you try `\vfill` or `\vfil`?

Comment: In principle I want `vfill` (or `vfil`). But it didn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by *didn't work*? Please, explain better what is the desired output.

Comment: Maybe `\vspace{.1\textheight}`

Comment: For A4, `\vspace{0.42\textheight}` looks like I want it. But for A5 this will result in two pages. So `\vspace{X\textheight}` does not solve the problem.

Comment: Well I think you should use the environment `titlepage` there you can get absolute control of the elements, position and layout of your title page. You need to replace the `\maketitle` with that environment... even if you don't need an inner second title page.

Comment: The result here looks nice https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/42709342/fastex-temp.pdf

Comment: I want the document to look like the two ones on the left side. With "it didn't work" I mean that it does not change anything. I can insert `\vfill` where I currently have `\vspace{10cm}` or I can remove `\vspace{10cm}` completely. The output pdf (generated by `pdflatex`) looks identical.

Comment: @moose Your preamble is *very* confused and you have several packages after `hyperref` that should go before it. Follow the suggestions and use the `titlepage` environment.

Comment: Still interested in solving the matter? If yes, please update the question. If not, we might close it with our next »answer the unanswered«. You might also be interested in [How to make a titlepage?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209993/how-to-add-a-flyleaf-code/210280#210280)

Comment: @Johannes_B: To be honest, I think I finished the related project and I think I found a work-around. Without reading my question again, I don't even remember the problem. I certainly can't add more details now.

However, I might find some time to read it next week (I have to finish my bachelor's thesis until next Monday and I'm still changing some of the content)