# How to replace the title page in Lyx's Thesis template?

Tags: lyx

I would like to replace the title page in [Lyx's thesis template](https://wiki.lyx.org/Examples/Thesis) by a PDF page.

I tried using `pdfseparate` and `pdfunite` from poppler-utils. It works but separating all pages and reuniting them looses hyperlinks used to navigate from the table of content.

I would prefer a Lyx / Latex solution. I inserted the pdf document in Lyx. But then an error comes when I remove the title: "! LaTeX Error: No \title given.".

Is it possible to remove title, author, subject and all element from the title page while still being able to compile a pdf file?

Comment: This is a non Latex solution that works for me now `pdftk A=university_title_page.pdf B=thesis.pdf cat A B2-131 output outfile.pdf` based on [this site](https://www.maketecheasier.com/combine-multiple-pdf-files-with-pdftk/)

Comment: Delete the LyX titlepage and include your pdf using pacage `pdfpages`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be caused by the "KOMA-Script Book layout" that this template uses. A quick solution is to add `\renewcommand\maketitle{}` to your preamble.

Comment: Thanks, I added `\usepackage{pdfpages}` in document / settings / Latex preamble.  Then I replaced the complete first page in the Lyx document by this Evil Red Text: `\includepdf{university_title_page}` based on this answer and  `\renewcommand\maketitle{}` based on your answer.

Comment: Oh, btw, instead of the preamble + Evil Red Text technique, you could also have clicked on `Insert > File > External Material...`, supply the path to your PDF file there, and select "PDF pages" from the dropdown menu. :)

Comment: Thanks, I added this information in the [Lyx wiki page on thesis templates](https://wiki.lyx.org/Examples/Thesis).

Comment: An [this is the answer on pdfpages](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14698/44254) I wanted to link to in my earlier comment.